# Is there a way for a caller of multiple functions to forward a function ref to selected functions in a purely functional way?

Tags: python, functional-programming, pipeline

### Problem

I have a function make_pipeline that accepts an arbitrary number of functions, which it then calls to perform sequential data transformation. The resulting call chain performs transformations on  a `pandas.DataFrame`. Some, but not all functions that it *may* call need to operate on a sub-array of the `DataFrame`. I have written multiple selector functions. However at present **each** member-function of the chain has to be explicitly be given the user-selected selector/filter function. This is **VERY** error-prone and accessibility is very important as the end-code is addressed to non-specialists (possibly with no Python/programming knowledge), so it must be "batteries-included". This entire project is written in a functional style (that's what's always worked for me).

### Sample Code

```
filter_func = simple_filter()
# The API looks like this
make_pipeline(
    load_data("somepath", header = [1,0]),
    transform1(arg1,arg2),
    transform2(arg1,arg2, data_filter = filter_func),# This function needs access to user-defined filter function
    transform3(arg1,arg2,, data_filter = filter_func),# This function needs access to user-defined filter function
    transform4(arg1,arg2),
)
```

### Expected API

```
filter_func = simple_filter()
# The API looks like this
make_pipeline(
    load_data("somepath", header = [1,0]),
    transform1(arg1,arg2),
    transform2(arg1,arg2),
    transform3(arg1,arg2),
    transform4(arg1,arg2),
)
```

#### Attempted

I thought that if the data_filter alias is available in the caller's namespace, it also becomes available (something similar to a closure) to all functions it calls. This seems to happen with some toy examples but wont work in the case (`UnboundError`).

What's a good way to make a function defined in one place available to certain interested functions in the call chain? I'm trying to avoid `global`.

### Notes/Clarification

- I've had problems with OOP and mutable states in the past, and functional programming has worked quite well. Hence I've set a goal for myself to NOT use classes (to the extent that Python enables me to anyways). So no classes.
- I should have probably clarified this initially: In the pipeline the output of all functions is a `DataFrame` and the input of all functions (except load data obviously) is a `DataFrame`. The functions are decorated with a wrapper that calls `functools.partial` because we want the user to supply the args to each function but not execute it. The actual execution is done be a forloop in `make_pipeline`.
- Each function accepts `df:pandas.DataFrame` plus all arguements that are specific to that function. The statement seen above `transform1(arg1,arg2,...)` actually calls the decorated `transform1` witch returns `functools.partial(transform, arg1,arg2,...)` which is now has a signature like `transform(df:pandas.DataFrame)`.
- `load_dataframe` is just a convenience function to load the initial dataframe so that all other functions can begin operating on it. It just felt more intuitive to users to have it part of the chain rather that a separate call
- The problem is this: I need a way for a filter function to be initialized (called) in only on place, such that every function in the call chain that needs access to the filter function, gets it ***without it being explicitly passed as argument to said function***. If you're wondering why this is the case, it's because I feel that end users will find it unintuitive and arbitrary. Some functions need it, some don't. I'm also pretty certain that they will make all kinds of errors like passing different filters, forgetting it sometimes etc.
- (Update) I've also tried `inspect.signature()` in make_pipeline to check if each function accepts a `data_filter` argument and pass it on. However, this raises an incorrect function signature error so some unclear reason (likely because of the decorators/partial calls). If signature could the return the non-partial function signature, this *would* solve the issue, but I couldn't find much info in the docs

Comment: I can't say I fully understood, but a suggestion anyway: If you are avoiding globals, what about putting your functions inside a class and have an instance variable?

Comment: so...`load_data` returns the dataframe to work on?  and `transform1(arg1, arg2)` returns a function to be called later by the pipeline?

Comment: So you want a functional style with impure functions? Those two goals seem to be at odds. I think OOP is a better approach here.

Comment: In your expected API, how do you specify which transforms use with filters?

Comment: @wjandrea impure how? Because of the shared "state" of the function ref? Hardly seems to matter since it isn't mutable in practice. @chepner Currently I pass the filter function explicitly, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I've also tried setting it inside `make_pipelines`, as I mention however, it does not seem to available inside the called function's namespace. I've considered passing down the call chain as a return value, but this solution seems pretty crude and kinda reaching

Comment: @arod "Impure" meaning you could get different results by binding the name `filter_func` differently. A non-local variable makes a function impure. Mutability is beside the point.

Comment: On second thought, would it be possible for `make_pipeline` to take the filter function as an argument? It would know which transform functions to pass it to, right?

Comment: @wjandrea That's the expected behavior, although if you have a better suggestion go ahead. I don't think so, unless it can somehow check if a function's signature I don't see how it would know. It's just doing an `e = arg(e) ` in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty easy. The solution is `inspect.signature`.

```
def make_pipeline(*args, data_filter:Optional[Callable[...,Any]] = None)
    d = args[0]
    for arg in args[1:]:
       if "data_filter" in inspect.signature(arg):
           d = arg(d, data_filter = data_filter)
       else:
           d= arg(d)
```

Leaving this here mostly for reference  because I think this is a mini design pattern. I've also seen an `function._closure_` on unrelated subject. That may also work, but will likely be more complicated.